# External SVG sprites and .childnodes

Tags: javascript, html, svg, xmlhttprequest

I have a site with several svg icons and svg logo that I have to animate.

For a better readability, I use a sprite system on an external file.

I use XMLHttpRequests to load sprites at the beginning of the request.

```
    function getSprites(url){

    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.open("GET", url, true);
        ajax.send();
        ajax.onload = function() {

            var div = document.createElement("div");
            div.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
            document.body.insertBefore(div, document.body.childNodes[0]);
    }

}

getSprites("./assets/images/sprites-icon.svg");
getSprites("./assets/images/sprites-logo.svg");
```

as soon as I use queryselector to select an element and animate it, this one is undefined

for example

```
    let shapeLogoRoadmap = document.querySelector('.js-shape-roadmap-logo').childNodes;
```

and here an example of svg symbol from sprite

```
 <symbol id="roadmap-small-logo" viewBox="0 0 250 250">
  <g class="js-shape-roadmap-logo">
    <path fill="#93718d" style="fill: var(--first-color, #93718d)" filter="url(#AI_Shadow_2)" d="M219.4366,111.5074l-80.944-80.944a19.1431,19.1431,0,0,0-26.9852,0l-80.944,80.944a19.1431,19.1431,0,0,0,0,26.9852l80.944,80.944a19.1431,19.1431,0,0,0,26.9852,0l80.944-80.944A19.1431,19.1431,0,0,0,219.4366,111.5074ZM200.5485,135.791,135.791,200.5485a15.3013,15.3013,0,0,1-21.582,0L49.4515,135.791a15.3013,15.3013,0,0,1,0-21.582L114.209,49.4515a15.3013,15.3013,0,0,1,21.582,0l64.7575,64.7575A15.3013,15.3013,0,0,1,200.5485,135.791Z"/>
    <path fill="#977792" style="fill: var(--second-color, #977792)" filter="url(#AI_Shadow_2)" d="M201.15,114.1231,135.8769,48.85a15.4233,15.4233,0,0,0-21.7538,0L48.85,114.1231a15.4233,15.4233,0,0,0,0,21.7538L114.1231,201.15a15.4233,15.4233,0,0,0,21.7538,0L201.15,135.8769A15.4233,15.4233,0,0,0,201.15,114.1231Zm-15.2308,19.5807-52.2154,52.2154a12.3428,12.3428,0,0,1-17.4077,0L64.0808,133.7038a12.3428,12.3428,0,0,1,0-17.4077l52.2153-52.2153a12.3428,12.3428,0,0,1,17.4077,0l52.2154,52.2153A12.3428,12.3428,0,0,1,185.9192,133.7038Z"/>
    <path fill="#9c7d96" style="fill: var(--third-color, #9c7d96)" filter="url(#AI_Shadow_2)" d="M185.9192,116.2961,133.7038,64.0808a12.3428,12.3428,0,0,0-17.4077,0L64.0808,116.2961a12.3428,12.3428,0,0,0,0,17.4077l52.2153,52.2154a12.3428,12.3428,0,0,0,17.4077,0l52.2154-52.2154A12.3428,12.3428,0,0,0,185.9192,116.2961Zm-12.1846,15.6654-41.7731,41.7731a9.87,9.87,0,0,1-13.923,0L76.2654,131.9615a9.87,9.87,0,0,1,0-13.923l41.7731-41.7731a9.87,9.87,0,0,1,13.923,0l41.7731,41.7731A9.87,9.87,0,0,1,173.7346,131.9615Z"/>
    <path fill="#a0829b" style="fill: var(--fourth-color, #a0829b)" filter="url(#AI_Shadow_2)" d="M173.7346,118.0385,131.9615,76.2654a9.87,9.87,0,0,0-13.923,0L76.2654,118.0385a9.87,9.87,0,0,0,0,13.923l41.7731,41.7731a9.87,9.87,0,0,0,13.923,0l41.7731-41.7731A9.87,9.87,0,0,0,173.7346,118.0385Zm-9.7461,12.5307-33.4193,33.4193a7.8951,7.8951,0,0,1-11.1384,0L86.0115,130.5692a7.8951,7.8951,0,0,1,0-11.1384l33.4193-33.4193a7.8949,7.8949,0,0,1,11.1384,0l33.4193,33.4193A7.8951,7.8951,0,0,1,163.9885,130.5692Z"/>
    <path fill="#a98ea4" style="fill: var(--fifth-color, #a98ea4)" filter="url(#AI_Shadow_2)" d="M163.9885,130.5692l-33.4193,33.4193a7.8951,7.8951,0,0,1-11.1384,0L86.0115,130.5692a7.8951,7.8951,0,0,1,0-11.1384l33.4193-33.4193a7.8949,7.8949,0,0,1,11.1384,0l33.4193,33.4193A7.8951,7.8951,0,0,1,163.9885,130.5692Z"/>
  </g>
</symbol>
```

I tried setinterval on animation but without success

In this situation, I want to have access to each path because I animate them one after the other.

Should I give them the same class name? or?

svg are as clear as possible, but I prefer to avoid inline svg but if there is no other better solution....

I need to have access to each path of the svg, the animations are not just transferring an image from right to left but a little more complex

I use gsap to animate just for information

I read that you can have problems with childnodes in this kind of situation?

To summarize, I would like to be able to manage each path of my svg, keeping a good organization.

Thx !

Once the page is loaded, in the console, I have access to the paths

[image]

When I refresh the page mutltiple time, sometimes it works !! :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution with the help of the GSAP forum.

Clean!

Thx Blake from GSAP

```
window.mySvg = window.mySvg || {};
window.mySvg.logo = `

    <svg>
       ... 
    </svg>

`;
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", mySvg.logo);
```